# SQL Server : Insert into Multiple Tables with Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a project tracking grocery expenses. I have the following tables with predefined values already inserted:

- Store (where we bought the food)
- Shopper (me or my wife)
- Category (of food)

I also have tables that are awaiting input.

They are:

- Receipt (one shopping trip with multiple food items)
- Food (each food item)
- FoodReceipt (bridge table between Receipt and Food)

I have my constraints set up the way I need them, but I am at a bit of a loss when it comes to writing an INSERT statement that would allow me to insert a new record that references values in the other tables. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that Food is also a table that already exists - you are not creating new food rows when you are writeing receipts. If thats the case then its a matter of writing the receipt, then retrieving the new key with @@identity or @@scope_identity, and writing the FoodReceipt rows. Alternatively if you can identify the receipt by other means then you can look it up as part of your insert statement. This sort of thing is easiest if you wrap it all in a stored procedure where you can handle all the lookups etc.

Comment: Cool, that helps.  I'm looking at writing a stored procedure now.

Answer (score 1):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` will give you the single value of the last identity.  While it may well work in this case, that isn't necessarily the best approach in the general case when you want to insert in sets.

I'd consider using the `OUTPUT` clause to output the inserted items ID into a temp table, then you can join them back to the subsequent inserts.

`INSERT INTO... OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO tempIDs

INSERT INTO other_table inner join tempIDs ...`

Wrap it up in a SP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Using the final three tables as an example, insert into the reciept table and use the ScopeIdentity() function to get the id (you have to use an identity column as the primary key). Repeat the following for each food item - insert into the food table, use ScopeIdentity to get the primary key and then insert a row into FoodReceipt the saved value for the receipt and the saved value for the current food row.